# Create html list from php var

Tags: php, html, arrays

I would like to know how I can convert a var into a list

from this php:

```
<? $data = "list 1|list 2|list 3|list 4|list 5"; ?>
```

to this:

```
<ul>
    <li>list 1</li>
    <li>list 2</li>
    <li>list 3</li>
    <li>list 4</li>
    <li>list 5</li>
</ul>
```

If it can be done in a php function it would be way better, I know it has to be made an "**array**" first and then use the "**foreach**" command, but there is where im stuck

Please help :)

Comment: You are thinking in the right direction. You might want to look into the explode method too.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really have to store it in array, [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) will take care of it, do the following:

```
<?php
 $data = explode('|', "list 1|list 2|list 3|list 4|list 5");
 echo '<ul>';
 foreach ($data as $val) {
   echo '<li>'.$val.'</li>';
 }
 echo '</ul>';
?>
```

This will handle it for you

Comment: Yup ^ and to see more (as well as this exact problem turned into an example oddly enough - #3) - visit here http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php